# visual code java ignores ~/.m2

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

Setting up a boot spring example from [here](http:////github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git) works fine from the terminal but Visual Code complains about missing dependencies. Explicitly putting them into settings.json doesn't help. It seems that the ~/.m2 repository is entirely ignored, even it should be supported according to the docs. Does anybody experienced similar issues or does anybody has some advice? Thank you.

[image: See Screenshot here.]